# Alphametics Question

Tags: arithmetic, contest-math, puzzle, cryptarithm

> In the figure below, each distinct letter represents a unique digit
> such that the arithmetic sum holds. If the letter L represents 9, what
> is the digit represented by the letter T?
>
> ```
>      TERRIBLE
>   +    NUMBER
>    ==========
>      THIRTEEN
> ```

I know I can get the answer for this puzzle but I'm struggling to see how to solve it. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

9+E = E cannot hold, unless 1 was carried from the right. This implies E+R = 10 + N. In that case 1 is carried to the left. There B+B+1 = E makes E odd. R+U = R can only hold for U = 9 and 1 from the right, but L = 9, so U = 0. E and H are distinct numbers, so H = E+1 and thus R+N = 10+I.

This is enough to significantly reduce the number of cases. We need E odd and R, E, N somewhat large. Also, H = E+1 takes up one large number. If E = 7, then H = 8, and since L = 9, we can't take R large enough for R+N > 10 to hold. If E = 3, or E = 5 and R = 7 again R+N < 10. Thus we must have E = 5, R = 8.

I'll leave it for you to finish.

Comment: You are definetely correct; but look at this: $?5881295 + 30?258 = ?618?553$ The addition cannot hold, since $?$ can be only $4$ or $7$

Comment: @RiccardoDelMonte: Let B be 7.

Comment: @Kundor Thanks, got it.